# What is this machine's purpose?

Tags: construction

I was driving past a house under construction and saw this device in its driveway. It was operating, making a continual noise. Does anyone know what this machine is and what it does?

[image]

Comment: [It passes butter.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ht-ZyJOV2k)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like a fan-forced portable furnace, to blow warmed air into the cold building that is being built.

Comment: Would this be called a mobile indirect fired air heater? The purpose is to have all combustion gasses exhausted out side while a heat exchanger warms the air delivered to the inside through the flex duct.  I would never have known they existed with out your answer.

Comment: I'm up in Canada, eh?

Comment: @Kris It's definitely a mobile air heater, can't say about the rest of your description.